# Jquery submit form having issue on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating search form, when user click search icon, i need to show textbox, once i entered content, and again clicked same search icon, it needs to display search results. Below is the code i used.

HTML & Javascript

```
<div class="search_right"> 
<div class="search-top-container">
<div class="search-top"></div>
<div class="search-form">
<div class="search-form-border"></div>
<div class="search-top-title"><span class="icon"></span>Search</div>
<form id="search_mini_form" action="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/search.php" method="get">
 <div class="form-search">
 <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" style="display:none;" autocomplete="off">
  <button type="submit" title="Search" id="but" onclick="tog_input();" >    
  </button>
  </div>
  <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function tog_input(){ 
  if(jQuery("#search").is(':visible'))
  {         
  if(jQuery("#search").val()!=''){ jQuery("#search_mini_form").submit();    
  }else{
  jQuery("#search").animate({ width: 'hide' }); 
  }
  }
  else
  {
  jQuery("#search").animate({ width: 'show' }); 
  } 
  }
  </script>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
```

Right now issue is, when i clicked search icon, it showing search page instead of textbox, any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the inline code from:

```
<button type="submit" title="Search" id="but" onclick="tog_input();">Submit</button>
```

To:

```
<button type="submit" title="Search" id="but" onclick="tog_input(this, event);">Submit</button>
```

Avoid this line:

```
jQuery("#search_mini_form").submit();
```

Prevent the form submission only when needed.

So:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="search_right">
    <div class="search-top-container">
        <div class="search-top"></div>
        <div class="search-form">
            <div class="search-form-border"></div>
            <div class="search-top-title"><span class="icon"></span>Search</div>
            <form id="search_mini_form" action="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/search.php" method="get">
                <div class="form-search">
                    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" style="display:none;"
                           autocomplete="off">
                    <button type="submit" title="Search" id="but" onclick="tog_input(this, event);">Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    function tog_input(obj, e) {

                        if (jQuery("#search").is(':visible')) {

                            if (jQuery("#search").val() == '') {

                                jQuery("#search").animate({width: 'hide'});
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                        else {

                            e.preventDefault();

                            jQuery("#search").animate({width: 'show'});
                        }
                    }
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that it is because your button type is submit. If you change it to button type = "button" then it should work, although you may need another button to submit your form.

Comment: Thanks, i tired, its not working. i refered one website. http://qdsociety.com/ I tried to implement same feature like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default behaviour of submit button else it will end up in action page. To achieve it you need to do as -

```
function tog_input(e){ 
   e.preventDefault();// prevents default action
   ... other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for code, when i used preventdefault, click action not working., i need to show text box on first time clicked button and after that i will enter text and again i will click same button.

Comment: please, check your loop conditions as default submit behaviour is prevented you can now have jquery/js functions. `console.log()` your conditions/variables you will find a way.